# Trying to install axios on a React project via npm i axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, axios

When I run npm i axios I get the following errors:

C:\Users\Mary\star-wars>npm i axios
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/axios/-/axios-0.27.2.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'axios@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/axios/-/axios-0.27.2.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-07T14_23_38_747Z-debug-0.log

I can´t find anything that works for me, I´ve tried to reinstall dependencies, I´ve tried to unistall axios and re-install it without success.
I´ve checked the log & it contains the same error that shows when I run the command.
Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: are you behind corporate proxy?

Comment: no, i just realize it won´t let me run npx create-react-app either, i tried uninstalling nodejs, reinstalling it, tried running create-react-app again and i get the same errors

Comment: i tried npm cache clean -f, same error....

Comment: I´ve tried npm init to create a package.json, same error

Comment: and I can run npm start on another project

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do what I intended by running it as  Admin, creating a different folder, running npm cache clean -f and setting npm. registry
After that, everything went smooth.